# Issue with Protractor .all locator

Tags: angular, automation, protractor

Has anyone encountered an issue where .all locator does not return any elements, although when the locator is tested in chrome console, it returns only the first element.
Example:

```
<datagrid>
    <row/>
     <row/>
</datagrid>

let rows=element(by.css(datagrid)).all(by.css(row))
```

returns zero results in my code, or just the first element?

Another issue I have is that csscontainingtext does not work with a regexp although protractor version is 5.4.2...
I am staring to wonder whether these are bugs, or some angular configurations that mess up the protractor testing. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks correct, did you try wait a long time before finding them? for `csscontainingtext` issue, After read `protractor 5.4.2` code, it should work.  [https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.2/lib/locators.ts#L421] [https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.2/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L686], can you sharing your code of using it and the html code of elements to find.

Comment: Yes, tried to wait/ debug, still doesn't return. Also, there are no iframes to mess with protractor.

Answer (score 0):

Try with quotes:

`let rows = element(by.css('datagrid')).all(by.css('row'));`

or even:

`let rows = element.all(by.css('datagrid > row'));`

Comment: Sorry, it's just my example in the question. Otherwise my code syntax is correct, so that's not the issue